# Move turtles random steps forward

Tags: netlogo

I'm currently starting to learn NetLogo, and I'm trying to make four turtles race from the ground's top to the bottom. I'm trying to use a while command, and the check does not detect any issues. However, when I click the button, the turtles do not move.

```
to setupTurtles
  ca
  crt 4
  ask turtles [set shape "turtle" set heading 180]
  ask turtle 0 [set xcor 8 set ycor 16]
  ask turtle 1 [set xcor 4 set ycor 16]
  ask turtle 2 [set xcor -4 set ycor 16]
  ask turtle 3 [set xcor -8 set ycor 16]
end

to moveTurtles
  while [all? turtles [ycor != 16]] [
    ask turtles [fd random 5]
    ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't move because they **start** at `ycor = 16`. The

```
[all? turtles [ycor != 16]]
```

condition means: "is every turtle on a `ycor` different from 16?". Since they start at `ycor = 16`, the condition evaluates as `FALSE`.

Change the condition to

```
[not any? turtles with [ycor = -16]]
```

which reads as: "(while) there is no turtle on a `ycor` of -16, i.e. the bottom, (do stuff)".